# Trouble Configuring NGINX as Load Balancer for MERN Stack App in Docker Compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am working on a MERN stack app and have already dockerized my project. However, I am facing issues while configuring NGINX for the app, and I also want to set up NGINX as a load balancer. Below is my Docker Compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  client:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: abin11/tutortrek_client:latest
    container_name: tutortrek_client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - ./client/.env
    depends_on:
      - server
    networks:
      - connection_network
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 1G
        reservations:
          memory: 512M
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: abin11/tutortrek_server:latest
    env_file:
      - ./server/.env
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - connection_network
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:4000/health"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    volumes:
      - .db:/data
    restart: always
    networks:
      - connection_network

  nginx:
   image: nginx:latest
   volumes:
     - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d 
     - ./client/build:/usr/share/nginx/html
   depends_on:
     - server
   ports:
     - "4000:4000" 
   networks:
     - connection_network


networks:
  connection_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Additionally, here is my NGINX configuration to serve the Node.js server and the React app. As a newcomer to NGINX, I'm unsure whether this configuration is correct:

```
http {
    upstream server_backend {
        server server:4000;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name tutortrek.online;
        location / {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://server;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        }

    }
}
```

After running the containers, all services are up and running correctly, except for NGINX. It seems NGINX is unable to access the server and client, leading to a 502 Bad Gateway error when I try to access the URL.

How can I properly configure NGINX to handle my full-stack app and set up load balancing for the server using Docker Compose's --scale command?